# java gui image problem : doesn't display in the background

Tags: java, image, user-interface, swing

i have a query about why is my image not being displayed in my background of my program. I mean i did all the steps necessary and still it would'nt be displayed. The code runs perfectly but without having the image displayed. The directory is written in the good location of the image. I am using java with gui. If anyone could help me solve my problem, i would appreciate :) here is the code below:

```
import java.awt.*; 
import java.awt.event.*; 
import javax.swing.*;

public class hehe extends JPanel{

    public hehe(){

            setOpaque(false);
            setLayout(new FlowLayout()); 
          }

    public static void main (String args[]){
           JFrame win = new JFrame("yooooo"); // it is automaticcally hidden

           JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout()); 
                win.add(mainPanel);

     JLabel titleLabel = new JLabel("title boss"); 
           titleLabel.setFont(new Font("Arial",Font.BOLD,18)); 
           titleLabel.setForeground(Color.blue);
           mainPanel.add(titleLabel,BorderLayout.NORTH);

           win.setSize(382,269); // the dimensions of the image
           win.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
           win.setVisible(true);
        }


            public void paint(Graphics g) {

                      Image a = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("C:\\Users\\andrea\\Desktop\\Gui\\car"); // car is the name of the image file and is in JPEG
                g.drawImage(a,0,0,getSize().width,getSize().height,this);
                super.paint(g);
            }
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code you have provided there is no reference to the hehe class in your main() method. I am guessing you would want to create that object and add it to your window.

Also you would need to include the .jpg extension in the file name

Comment: did the extension, i'll try to create the object

Comment: You mean like putting this:      hehe c = new hehe();                // skip a line                              win.add(c);                         is that what you meant?

Comment: Yes that would be how you create the hehe object. I was meaning change your code and then edit the question to show your new code. I am still not quite clear on what you are trying to do. I am guessing you would want to make the mainPanel opaque as well to make it show the hehe panel below.

Comment: what exactly i want to do is to make my JPEG image file displayed on the background of the program during its execution, and this isnt happening.

Answer (score 1):

super.paint() draws background after painting your image and your image is hidden.
Try to setOpaque(false) or change the order call super.paint() before painting image.

Also avoid obtaining image in paint() method. Paint is called very often so you read your image every time on paint(). Create a field for the image and read it once on creation.

Comment: setOpaque(false) is already false, u meant setting it true? it still remained with no desktop background. i trying putting the super.paint() before the line starting - Image a ... - and the line starting - g.drawImage.. _ but still no effec. I am really confused.